# string - юникод, мультибайт

Tags: c++, строки, unicode

Очень интересно есть ли универсальный макрос для "string" "wstring", который будет подставляться в зависимости от указанной кодировке проекта, как например TCHAR или нужно писать макрос самому?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно писать самому. Но это сделать довольно легко. Есть пара вариантов реализации:

- ```
  typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring;
  ```
- ```
  #ifdef _UNICODE
  typedef std::wstring tstring;
  #else
  typedef std::string tstring;
  #endif
  ```

Comment: спасибо, я также реализовал второй вариант, но голосую за твой первый вариант - кода меньше)